# Factory already registered error on rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using factory-bot (factory-girl) when i'm testing my rails project. 
When i run 'rspec' with development environments tests are working well but if i run it like 'RAILS_ENV=test rspec' i'm gettin factory already registered for each factory.

Is there anyone who has an idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: `rspec` executes by default for test environment

Comment: Can you see exactly which factory is already registered in the error log?

Comment: It gives the same error for every factory. It's like running all factories twice. But the problem is if i run it just 'rspec' it works without any error.

Comment: As Mikhail has stated ... rspec should be running in test environment by default anyway ... RAILS_ENV should be defined at the top of your rails_helper.rb file. Might be worth posting that file in your question anyway ... as well as spec_helper.rb